# Subject math GRE exam 0568 Q.46

Tags: group-homomorphism, gre-exam

This is the question with its answer:[image]

It is not clear for me why we should show the first statement in the following picture:[image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Actually the offered solution **is wrong** when it says II (or I) follows from III -- that would be the case if III claimed that all the maps $z\mapsto z^k$ are homomorphisms, but actually it only claims that all homomorphisms are _among_ those maps.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, but actually in this case $z\mapsto z^k$ is homomorphism $\forall k$. Of course, III  doesn't say it.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: True enough, of course; it is just not what III in the problem states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $i$ generates the group then $z=i^m$ for some $m$. Now, if $i$ maps to $i^k$ then $z$ maps to $i^{mk}=z^k$ following the homomorphism properties.